Assigning Color Won't Work
I am trying to make a palette-swap shader. Here is my code:
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform vec4 origin:source_color;
uniform vec4 new:source_color;

void fragment(){
   vec4 current_color = texture(TEXTURE,UV);
   if (distance(current_color,origin)<0.01){
      COLOR = new;
   }
}

I've tried adjusting the 0.01 value, but nothing works. This is assigned to the Material of a Sprite2D and AnimatedSprite2D. Neither of them works: none of the pixels change colors.
How can I make it so it swaps a pixel of a certain color, with another color?

You haven't described the result you are getting beyond "nothing works". What I can tell at a glance is that you are not outputting the original color where you don't want to change it.

I have made it output the original color. But the result is nothing changes.

First off - remove the if altogether and try to directly assign the new color. Further debugging will depend on the results..

@Kromster this works and fills the whole area with the color new

So.. the issue seems to be with the condition of the if itself

It seems so. I've tried several method, including comparing colors with == and creating a custom function to see if they were equal (It didn't work well)

This shader works for me. Have you considered the alpha value of the color?

The alpha value is fine. I checked. This is strange. I should try this on another device.

I think the problem is not with the shader itself. You can try void fragment(){COLOR = new;}, if the sprite still doesn't change, it's more likely to be a scene setup/resource issue.

@Mangata I tried it with a completely new Project. Different images. Even with a ColorRect, and it is all still the same result.
Also void fragment(){COLOR=new;} does change the whole sprite to the color new


Perhaps because the original color had an alpha value accidentally set, none of the pixels passed the decision. My suggestion is to set a threshold parameter slider for easier debugging, and remove alpha:
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform vec3 origin:source_color;
uniform vec3 new:source_color;
uniform float threshold : hint_range(0, 2);

void fragment(){
   vec3 current_color = texture(TEXTURE,UV).rgb;
   if (distance(current_color,origin)<threshold){
      COLOR.rgb = new;
   }
}

